# Make Outlook HTML template button background transparent in Outlook Black Theme mode

Tags: html, css, button, label, transparent

Good afternoon.

I hope that you are well.

I have just created and Outlook 365 HTML template email which contains a button which launches a link when pressed.

The outline of the button is green and the text is white.

The button text displays as expected when the Outlook Office Theme is set to any of the following settings :-
Colorful, Dark Gray or White

However when the theme is set to Black, the button text goes black and contains a square border around it in a different shade of green.  Is there a way to either remove the erroneous green background or make it transparent please?

The following image displays the difference detailed above :-
[image: app example]

Many thanks in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:AllowPNG/><o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch></o:OfficeDocumentSettings></xml><![endif]-->
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport"/>
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<!--<![endif]-->
<title></title>
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<!--<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        table,
        td,
        tr {
            vertical-align: top;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        * {
            line-height: inherit;
        }

        a[x-apple-data-detectors=true] {
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }
    </style>
<style id="media-query" type="text/css">
        @media (max-width: 720px) {

            .block-grid,
            .col {
                min-width: 320px !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                display: block !important;
            }

            .block-grid {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            .col {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            .col_cont {
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            img.fullwidth,
            img.fullwidthOnMobile {
                max-width: 100% !important;
            }

            .no-stack .col {
                min-width: 0 !important;
                display: table-cell !important;
            }

            .no-stack.two-up .col {
                width: 50% !important;
            }

            .no-stack .col.num2 {
                width: 16.6% !important;
            }

            .no-stack .col.num3 {
                width: 25% !important;
            }

            .no-stack .col.num4 {
                width: 33% !important;
            }

            .no-stack .col.num5 {
                width: 41.6% !important;
            }

            .no-stack .col.num6 {
                width: 50% !important;
            }

            .no-stack .col.num7 {
                width: 58.3% !important;
            }

            .no-stack .col.num8 {
                width: 66.6% !important;
            }

            .no-stack .col.num9 {
                width: 75% !important;
            }

            .no-stack .col.num10 {
                width: 83.3% !important;
            }

            .video-block {
                max-width: none !important;
            }

            .mobile_hide {
                min-height: 0px;
                max-height: 0px;
                max-width: 0px;
                display: none;
                overflow: hidden;
                font-size: 0px;
            }

            .desktop_hide {
                display: block !important;
                max-height: none !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="clean-body" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;">
<!--[if IE]><div class="ie-browser"><![endif]-->
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="nl-container" role="presentation" style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: top; min-width: 320px; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: #ffffff; width: 100%;" valign="top" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr style="vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
<td style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td align="center" style="background-color:#ffffff"><![endif]-->
<div style="background-color:transparent;">
<div class="block-grid" style="min-width: 320px; max-width: 700px; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; Margin: 0 auto; background-color: transparent;">
<div style="border-collapse: collapse;display: table;width: 100%;background-color:transparent;">
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:transparent;"><tr><td align="center"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:700px"><tr class="layout-full-width" style="background-color:transparent"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><td align="center" width="700" style="background-color:transparent;width:700px; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent;" valign="top"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-top:35px; padding-bottom:15px;"><![endif]-->
<div class="col num12" style="min-width: 320px; max-width: 700px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; width: 700px;">
<div class="col_cont" style="width:100% !important;">
<!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
<div style="border-top:0px solid transparent; border-left:0px solid transparent; border-bottom:0px solid transparent; border-right:0px solid transparent; padding-top:35px; padding-bottom:15px; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;">
<!--<![endif]-->
<div align="center" class="img-container center fixedwidth" style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;">
<!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr style="line-height:0px"><td style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;" align="center"><![endif]--><img align="center" alt="Alternate text" border="0" class="center fixedwidth" src="images/29c5b391-efef-4d9d-b511-8df7e3e65ff8.png" style="text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%; max-width: 670px; display: block;" title="Alternate text" width="670"/>
<!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
</div>
<!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif"><![endif]-->
<div style="color:#1e5d2c;font-family:Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;line-height:1.2;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">
<div style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.2; font-family: Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; color: #1e5d2c; mso-line-height-alt: 17px;">
<p style="font-size: 30px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center; word-break: break-word; font-family: Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; mso-line-height-alt: 36px; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 30px;"><strong>Application Validation Survey</strong></span></p>
</div>
</div>
<!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
<div align="center" class="img-container center autowidth" style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;">
<!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr style="line-height:0px"><td style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;" align="center"><![endif]--><img align="center" alt="Alternate text" border="0" class="center autowidth" src="images/pexels-photo-5553050-newedit.jpg" style="text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%; max-width: 670px; display: block;" title="Alternate text" width="670"/>
<!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
</div>
<!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
</div>
<!--<![endif]-->
</div>
</div>
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="background-color:transparent;">
<div class="block-grid" style="min-width: 320px; max-width: 700px; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; Margin: 0 auto; background-color: transparent;">
<div style="border-collapse: collapse;display: table;width: 100%;background-color:transparent;">
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:transparent;"><tr><td align="center"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:700px"><tr class="layout-full-width" style="background-color:transparent"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><td align="center" width="700" style="background-color:transparent;width:700px; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent;" valign="top"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:10px;"><![endif]-->
<div class="col num12" style="min-width: 320px; max-width: 700px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; width: 700px;">
<div class="col_cont" style="width:100% !important;">
<!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
<div style="border-top:0px solid transparent; border-left:0px solid transparent; border-bottom:0px solid transparent; border-right:0px solid transparent; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif"><![endif]-->
<div style="color:#555555;font-family:Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;line-height:1.8;padding-top:5px;padding-right:15px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:15px;">
<div style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.8; color: #555555; font-family: Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; mso-line-height-alt: 25px;">
<p style="text-align: left; line-height: 1.8; word-break: break-word; font-size: 18px; mso-line-height-alt: 32px; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Dear <strong>name</strong>,</span></p>
<p style="text-align: left; line-height: 1.8; word-break: break-word; font-size: 18px; mso-line-height-alt: 32px; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce luctus quam vitae ultricies vestibulum. Curabitur eget ex et ante porta semper ut id ligula. In aliquet tortor sit amet felis luctus egestas. Pellentesque varius enim eget elementum interdum. Ut tellus dolor, tristique nec aliquet ut, elementum maximus justo. Nulla tincidunt iaculis convallis. Suspendisse vel lacinia augue. Aliquam sed est quis ipsum tempor congue. Phasellus nec ex ac ex eleifend tempus. Curabitur tincidunt cursus libero, at fringilla nibh scelerisque sit amet. Fusce eros magna, aliquet eget viverra vel, gravida quis est. Donec lectus justo, cursus eu rhoncus sit amet, blandit id nunc.</span></p>
</div>
</div>
<!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
<!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif"><![endif]-->
<div style="color:#555555;font-family:Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;line-height:1.8;padding-top:5px;padding-right:15px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:15px;">
<div style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.8; color: #555555; font-family: Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; mso-line-height-alt: 25px;">
<p style="text-align: left; line-height: 1.8; word-break: break-word; font-size: 18px; mso-line-height-alt: 32px; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 18px;"><strong>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent justo eros, vestibulum in lacinia sit amet, ultricies nec purus.</strong> Sed eu odio tincidunt,<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="noopener" style="text-decoration: none; color: #f8b370;" target="_blank"> porttitor leo eu</a>, suscipit est. Sed mollis dolor condimentum mauris mattis, eu porttitor justo porttitor. </span></p>
</div>
</div>
<!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
<!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif"><![endif]-->
<div style="color:#777777;font-family:Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;line-height:1.8;padding-top:5px;padding-right:15px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:15px;">
<div style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.8; color: #777777; font-family: Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; mso-line-height-alt: 25px;">
<ul>
<li style="text-align: left; line-height: 1.8; word-break: break-word; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 29px;"><span style="font-size: 16px;"><strong>LOREM IPSUM</strong>, leo vitae tincidunt luctus, sapien lectus tempus urna, ut tempor mi tortor mollis enim. Fusce suscipit justo id blandit mattis. </span></li>
<li style="text-align: left; line-height: 1.8; word-break: break-word; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 29px;"><span style="font-size: 16px;"><strong>LOREM IPSUM</strong> ex ac ex eleifend tempus. Curabitur tincidunt cursus libero, at fringilla nibh scelerisque sit amet. Fusce eros magna, aliquet eget viverra vel, gravida quis est. Donec lectus justo, cursus eu rhoncus sit amet, blandit id nunc.</span></li>
<li style="text-align: left; line-height: 1.8; word-break: break-word; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 29px;"><span style="font-size: 16px;"><strong>LOREM IPSUM</strong> condimentum tellus, ac hendrerit ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
<!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif"><![endif]-->
<div style="color:#555555;font-family:Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;line-height:1.8;padding-top:5px;padding-right:15px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:15px;">
<div style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.8; color: #555555; font-family: Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; mso-line-height-alt: 25px;">
<p style="text-align: left; line-height: 1.8; word-break: break-word; font-size: 18px; mso-line-height-alt: 32px; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Sed eu odio Phasellus blandit dapibus orci, vitae sollicitudin tellus cursus eget. Praesent dignissim ante at magna scelerisque fermentum. Donec vel vulputate lorem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur quis condimentum tellus, ac hendrerit ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </span></p>
</div>
</div>
<!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
<div align="center" class="button-container" style="padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">
<!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;"><tr><td style="padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px" align="center"><v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.google.com" style="height:43.5pt; width:405.75pt; v-text-anchor:middle;" arcsize="61%" stroke="false" fillcolor="#1e5d2c"><w:anchorlock/><v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0"><center style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:24px"><![endif]--><a href="http://www.google.com" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; background-color: #1e5d2c; border-radius: 35px; -webkit-border-radius: 35px; -moz-border-radius: 35px; width: auto; width: auto; border-top: 1px solid #1e5d2c; border-right: 1px solid #1e5d2c; border-bottom: 1px solid #1e5d2c; border-left: 1px solid #1e5d2c; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family: Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; text-align: center; mso-border-alt: none; word-break: keep-all;" target="_blank"><span style="padding-left:40px;padding-right:40px;font-size:24px;display:inline-block;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 2; word-break: break-word; mso-line-height-alt: 32px;"><span data-mce-style="font-size: 24px; line-height: 48px;" style="font-size: 24px; line-height: 48px;"><strong>LAUNCH APPLICATION SURVEY</strong></span></span></span></a>
<!--[if mso]></center></v:textbox></v:roundrect></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
</div>
<!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
</div>
<!--<![endif]-->
</div>
</div>
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="background-color:transparent;">
<div class="block-grid" style="min-width: 320px; max-width: 700px; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; Margin: 0 auto; background-color: transparent;">
<div style="border-collapse: collapse;display: table;width: 100%;background-color:transparent;">
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:transparent;"><tr><td align="center"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:700px"><tr class="layout-full-width" style="background-color:transparent"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><td align="center" width="700" style="background-color:transparent;width:700px; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent;" valign="top"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;"><![endif]-->
<div class="col num12" style="min-width: 320px; max-width: 700px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; width: 700px;">
<div class="col_cont" style="width:100% !important;">
<!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
<div style="border-top:0px solid transparent; border-left:0px solid transparent; border-bottom:0px solid transparent; border-right:0px solid transparent; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif"><![endif]-->
<div style="color:#1e5d2c;font-family:Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;line-height:1.2;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">
<div style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.2; font-family: Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; color: #1e5d2c; mso-line-height-alt: 17px;">
<p style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center; word-break: break-word; font-family: Roboto, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; mso-line-height-alt: 24px; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 20px;"><strong>Contact Us</strong></span></p>
</div>
</div>
<!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
<div class="mobile_hide">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="social_icons" role="presentation" style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: top; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr style="vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
<td style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px;" valign="top">
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="social_table" role="presentation" style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: top; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-tspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; mso-table-bspace: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0;" valign="top">
<tbody>
<tr align="center" style="vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; text-align: center;" valign="top">
<td style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: 7.5px; padding-left: 7.5px;" valign="top"><a href="mailto:" target="_blank"><img alt="E-Mail" height="32" src="images/mail2x.png" style="text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; height: auto; border: 0; display: block;" title="E-Mail" width="32"/></a></td>
<td style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: 7.5px; padding-left: 7.5px;" valign="top"><a href="" target="_blank"><img alt="Web Site" height="32" src="images/website2x.png" style="text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; height: auto; border: 0; display: block;" title="Web Site" width="32"/></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="divider" role="presentation" style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: top; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; min-width: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr style="vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
<td class="divider_inner" style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top; min-width: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px;" valign="top">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="divider_content" height="10" role="presentation" style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: top; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-top: 0px solid transparent; height: 10px; width: 100%;" valign="top" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr style="vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
<td height="10" style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top"><span></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
</div>
<!--<![endif]-->
</div>
</div>
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!--[if (IE)]></div><![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit suggestion and forcing the change through zhisme.  Much appreciated as the post now looks better.

Comment: I have workaround this issue by creating the button as an image instead of generating the button in code.  The button displays as expected without the background colour issue when using the Black Office Theme within Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `user-select: none;` in CSS

```css
#colorful::selection {
  color: white;  
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<p>You can select me!</p>
<p style="user-select: none">You can't select me!</p>
<p id="colorful">I am coloured when I am selected</p>
```

Comment: That is great, thank you GucciBananaKing99.  Much appreciated.